# What is this receptacle?

Tags: receptacle

I had a friend send me a pic of this receptacle and plug, but I can't find what type/amperage it is. (Unfortunately I can't get a less-blurry pic.) Any info is appreciated!

[image: Unknown Receptacle]
[image: Unknown plug]

Comment: Yeah, that's 120V/30A with neutral and ground.  If your application is anything else, use a different plug and socket which is correct for that application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#/media/File:NEMA_simplified_pins.svg) it seems to be a NEMA TT-30 socket typically used in RV/Trailer appications:

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much.